# How TCP Server keeping NetworkStreams of each connecting client with corresponding sockets (Fleck Code reference )

Tags: c#, websocket, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am new to Sockets and have problems in understanding the overall picture of the TCP Socket Server implementation using the Fleck library. What I can conclude from my understanding so far regarding this is WebServer using WebSockets under the hood.

Client-server communication is established after having a handshake. Server housekeeps distinct sockets on each client connection which are used later on by the server to communicate with those clients.

The client socket assigned by the server has a network stream that it uses for communicating with the server.

However, the following code is used by Fleck to Accept and communicate with clients using only one network stream which is associated with its socket. I don't understand, how every client can be communicated only by the server socket underlying its network stream.

Here is the source code of the Server Socket.

```
public class SocketWrapper: ISocket
{      
        private readonly Socket _socket;
        private Stream _stream;
        private CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource;
        private TaskFactory _taskFactory;

        public SocketWrapper(Socket socket)
        {
            _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _taskFactory = new TaskFactory(_tokenSource.Token);
            _socket = socket;
            if (_socket.Connected)
                _stream = new NetworkStream(_socket);   // here server socket is being associated with network stream.
        }
        
        public Task<int> Receive(byte[] buffer, Action<int> callback, Action<Exception> error, int offset)
        {
            try
            {
                Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin =
               (cb, s) => _stream.BeginRead(buffer, offset, buffer.Length, cb, s); // Have a problem to understand here, how come the same server socket stream is being used for reading from any random client which is sending the data to server?

                Task<int> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync<int>(begin, _stream.EndRead, null);
                task.ContinueWith(t => callback(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
                    .ContinueWith(t => error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                task.ContinueWith(t => error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                return task;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error(e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public Task<ISocket> Accept(Action<ISocket> callback, Action<Exception> error)
        {
            Func<IAsyncResult, ISocket> end = r => _tokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested ? null : new SocketWrapper(_socket.EndAccept(r));
            var task = _taskFactory.FromAsync(_socket.BeginAccept, end, null);
            task.ContinueWith(t => callback(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
                .ContinueWith(t => error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            task.ContinueWith(t => error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            return task;
        }          

        public Task Send(byte[] buffer, Action callback, Action<Exception> error)
        {
            if (_tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                return null;

            try
            {
                Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin =
                    (cb, s) => _stream.BeginWrite(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cb, s); // How server could send the message to any specific client by using it's own network stream??

                Task task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(begin, _stream.EndWrite, null);
                task.ContinueWith(t => callback(), TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted)
                    .ContinueWith(t => error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                task.ContinueWith(t => error(t.Exception), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

                return task;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                error(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried to read on MSDN about the way server and client communicates, was not able to understand this fact which I tried to ask.

Comment: `Accept` returns a new child socket for every client. The original listening socket carries on listening, so you can call `Accept` again.